# Script in ltng:require Blocked by Locker Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, locker-service

I added a JavaScript file to a Static Resource and I'm using `ltng:require` to reference it in a Lightning component.

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.MyCommunity + '/js/myscript.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

**Controller:**

```
afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("script has loaded");
}
```

When I push this to my scratch org I see that Locker Service is blocking the file from executing:

```
<script data-locker-src="/core/resource/MyCommunity/js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Will Locker Service do this for every script? Is there a way around it?

Comment: It's not "blocked." This is simply how Locker Service sandboxes scripts.

Comment: @sfdcfox Is there a way to get around this so I can get my script to run? I don't see anything in the `ltng:require` documentation that suggests I need to do anything more: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require

Comment: What exactly is your script supposed to do? What do you observe? The more details we have, the better we can help you out.

Comment: @sfdxfox the script is provided by Qualtrics, it's so I can have a customer feedback pop-up happen when the page loads for users to rate the site (a 1-10 scale). The script works if I put in the Community <head> (Advanced > Edit Head), but that makes it pop-up on every page, so I want to put it in a component and load it only where we want it to pop-up.

Comment: Hi Matt, you should provide us with more information about the script. Maybe you're hitting an issue nobody has found so far!